# Stacked bar chart with custom gradient coloring

Tags: python, matplotlib, stacked-bar-chart

[image: Here's what I came up with by plotting thick line segments.]

Here's what I came up with by plotting thick line segments.
The coloration is blue, with varying alpha, 0 < alpha < 1.

My workaround doens't work as I'd like because I don't have a legend (I want a legend that shows a gradient of the blue at varying alpha).

Additionally, I've found that matplotlib scales funny. There should be no overlap of the bars, but if I adjust the window size, the gap between the line segments will change.[image: This is the same figure as the earlier one, just after I've resized the figure window with my mouse.]This is the same figure as the earlier one, just after I've resized the figure window with my mouse.

I'm not sure if there's a better way to go about accomplishing this, or if there's a different package I can use. 
Here's the snippet of code that I'm using.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x1  =[0, 19, 39, 46, 60, 79]
x2 = [19, 39, 46, 60, 79, 90]
alpha_list = [-0.8402, -0.6652, 0.0, -0.5106, -0.8074, 0.0]
plt.figure()
for idx,x in enumerate(x1):
    plt.plot([x1[idx],x2[idx]],[0,0],color = 'blue',alpha=alpha_list[idx],linewidth =20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you provide your code?

Comment: Just did, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose alpha is just a workaround for using different shades of blue? In that case the `Blues` colormap can be used instead.
Several lines can be plotted using a `LineCollection`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x1  =[0, 19, 39, 46, 60, 79]
x2 = [19, 39, 46, 60, 79, 90]
alpha_list = [-0.8402, -0.6652, 0.0, -0.5106, -0.8074, 0.0]

verts = np.dstack((np.c_[x1, x2], np.zeros((len(x1), 2))))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lc = LineCollection(verts, linewidth=40, cmap="Blues_r", array=np.array(alpha_list))
ax.add_collection(lc)

ax.autoscale()
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
fig.colorbar(lc)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I always wondered how to use `cmap` and line plots. Nice answer!

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

I think a workaround would be to use `plt.barh`.  Here is an example using normalized color maps.  Each color gets converted to RGBA before it can be passed to `plt.barh`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.cm as cmx

x1  =[0, 19, 39, 46, 60, 79]
x2 = [19, 39, 46, 60, 79, 90]

values = range(len(x1))
jet = cm = plt.get_cmap('jet') 
cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=values[-1])
scalarMap = cmx.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=jet)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for idx, x, y in zip(values,x1, x2):          
    colorVal = scalarMap.to_rgba(values[idx])  
    start = x
    end = y
    width=end-start
    ax.barh(y = 0, width = width, left=start, height = 0.1, label = str(idx), color=colorVal)         
ax.set_ylim(-.5,0.5)
ax.legend()
```

which returns:
[image]

If you really want to just change the alpha transparency of a single color, you would just have to input `alpha_list[idx`] for the last element to the RGBA tuple `colorVal`. For some reason, RGBA did not like negative alpha values, so notice I changed them all to positive

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
alpha_list = [0.8402, 0.6652, 0.01, 0.5106, 0.8074, 0.0]
for idx, x, y in zip(values,x1, x2):          
    colorVal = (0.0, 0.3, 1.0, alpha_list[idx])
    start = x
    end = y
    width=end-start
    ax.barh(y = 0, width = width, left=start, height = 0.1, label = str(idx), color=colorVal)         


ax.set_ylim(-.5,0.5)
ax.legend()
```

[image]